# Running Packages under a Proxy

Tags: ssis, database-administration

I am not sure if this is the best forum to post in but please bear with me. I am currently running SQL Server 2014 on a server that sits outside our company network i.e. not on the domain.  I am trying to run a SQL Job that executes a SSIS package on that server that process and moves files around on our network.

The problem is the package cant access the windows folders as the account it's running under, and if I remember correctly, is the SQLServerAgent Account doesn't have permission to access that location.  Because the Server Account sits outside the network I am not able to give it permission from the Windows side.

What I thought about doing was setting up a Proxy to run the package but again I am still having the same issues as I cant assign a Windows account from the network.  Also which is quite odd, if I right click the package it runs and works fine but when schedule it does not, so I am not sure how it works if I just log on to SQL Server as I am just using a SQL Login Account with all permissions.  So my question is, is it possible to get this to work using a proxy or if at all and why does it work if I run the package direct through management studio but not when scheduled?

I will supply any other information that might be needed to help solve this.

Comment: When you are in SSMS, you are likely your DomainUser and when the SSIS package attempts to access Domain resources, it uses your credentials. When you start from the NonDomain source, it doesn't have any an authorization token and Windows says pound sand

Comment: I assume adding a network share for Everyone doesn't work? (Obviously, bad from a security perspective)

Comment: Thanks for the comments billinkc, you are correct adding Everyone doesn't work and as you said from a security perspective not a good idea!